# Same schengen visa for return to different schengen country?

Tags: schengen

I am a F1 student studying in USA. I am planning to visit my home country via Rome. I'll be staying in Rome for a week, so I will be applying for schengen visa for Italy.

When returning back to USA from India after 15 days, I am planning to stay in Amsterdam for 3-4 days.

My question is, do I need to take another schengen visa for Netherlands, as my port of return flight entry will be Amsterdam or will my schengen visa for Italy work?

Comment: It depends what you get from Italy (single entry or multiple entry, dates of validity).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to apply for a single Schengen visa for 2 or multiple entries, covering the entire trip USA-Italy-India-Netherlands-USA.

Since Italy is your main destination (in this case, the Schengen country you will be staying the most days in), you must apply to the Italian consulate, but with itinerary and other documentation that covers your entire trip. The visa they issue should be valid for both parts of the trip.